# Add domain to Business Manager using Facebook Business Manager API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using the Facebook Business Manager API to automatically create new Child Business Managers using the 2-tier Business Manager solution.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/2tier-bm-solution

The only steps I am unable to find documentation for are adding a domain and exporting the DNS txt record for verification. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/verifying-your-domain/

Has anyone accomplished this using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by Facebook Engineering support that this endpoint doesn't exist (yet).